# What is the equation of parabola if the axis and the tangent at vertex are given?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

It is well known that the equation $y^2=kx$ represents (family of) parabola(s) with axis (of parabola) $y=0$ and tangent at vertex $x=0$.

Suppose instead we are given two mutually perpendicular lines $L_1:\ ax+by+c_1=0$ and $L_2:\ bx-ay+c_2=0$. Then we say that the equation of parabola with $L_1$ as the axis and $L_2$ as the tangent at vertex is
$$
\left(\frac{ax+by+c_1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2=k\left(\frac{bx-ay+c_2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right).
$$

One justification for this equation goes like this: the equation $y^2=kx$ can be seen as
$$
(\text{distance of $(x, y)$ from the line $y=0$})^2 = k(\text{distance of $(x, y)$ from the line $x=0$}).
$$

Then it is said that the second equation is the generalisation of this observation.

But I am not quite convinced on this generalisation. I think that there is some crucial detail missing. Please help me in why the second equation represents the parabola with axis $L_1$ and tangent at vertex $L_2$.

Comment: "I think that there is some crucial detail missing" Why? That justification looks fine to me.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca If that were the case then we had to prove that parabola is the locus of the point whose distance squared from one line, say $L$, is equal to some constant multiple to the distance to a line perpendicular to $L$. Can we prove this, in general (I mean not in just case for $y=0$ and $x=0$)?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Also I suspect that there is some role of rotation of parabola but I am not able to figure it out how.

Comment: It all depends on your definition of parabola, but in any case it is not difficult to prove that a parabola is the locus of the points whose distance squared from a line , is equal to some constant multiple of the distance to a line perpendicular to . This was proven for instance by Apollonius of Perga in the 3rd century b.C.

Comment: Read for instance Prop. IV here: https://archive.org/details/GeometryOfConics/page/n15/mode/1up

Comment: Thanks for supplying the geometric proof. Well similar properties holds for the case of ellipse and hyperbola too. From academics point of view, we usually don't study geometric proofs of all the properties of conics but we often deal them algebraically (or one may say analytically). It would be more helpful for me if you could give some algebraic explanation, for example, as I said above by using rotation of conics.

Comment: Do you mean you want to check the equation you get is really that of a parabola? Then expand the equation and compute the discriminant as explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form

Comment: Not exactly. What I am looking for is some algebraic explanation -- why the said generalisation works. Such generalisation works for Ellipse and Hyperbola too. Parabola is not a special case. I guess there is some general explanation that works for all three conics.

Comment: In fact, you'll find in that book linked above analogous proofs for ellipse and hyperbola. I'm sorry I don't understand what kind of "explanation" you are looking for. I hope someone else can help you.